# what are the things that aes cbc-mac , aes cmac guarantees?

Tags: aes, cbc-mac, ccm, cmac

does aes-cbc-mac guarantees integrity, authenticity and confidentiality?
does aes-cmac guarantees integrity, authenticity and confidentiality?
because I only know that aes-ccm guarantees all i.e. integrity , authenticity and confidentiality..

Comment: Please update your question by using the correct terms. Acronyms and starts of sentences should be capitalized. What have you tried to resolve this question? What kind of guarantees do you think that a MAC provides in general?

Comment: mac provides both authentication and integrity

Comment: Right, but note that CCM also allows Additional Data to be authenticated, which isn't encrypted.

Comment: yeah thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Aes-cbc-mac and aes-cmac offers only authencity and integrity because it deals with MAC.

Comment: Well done :) If ephemeral keys are used it will only offer *message* authenticity, by the way, not to be confused with entity authentication. And note that by default it only proves that the message was generated by somebody that has the key (which, for transport protocols, means both sender *and receiver(s)*).